# Magento 2 : escapeHtml & escapeHtmlAttr

Tags: magento2

what is the difference between the escapeHtml & escapeHtmlAttr
I can see there in magento 2.4 escapeHtml is replaced to escapeHtmlAttr in many phtml files.

I can seee no difference in output.

```
 <div> <?php echo $block->escapeHtml('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}'); ?> </div> <?php  echo'</br>'; ?> 
<div> <?php echo $block->escapeHtmlAttr('{"a":1,"b":2,"c":3,"d":4,"e":5}'); ?> </div> <?php  echo'</br>';
```

any thoughts on this what is the difference between both & when to use which method ?

Comment: any thoughts on this what is the difference between both & when to use which method ?

Answer (score 1):

As i know both **escapeHtml** and **escapeHtmlAttr** are using for preventing xss.

For use case, i always use:

- escapeHtml for render html content
- escapeHtmlAttr for render attribute of element

Another tips, as I know when you publish your module to market place, all code will be validated XSS prevention strategies

Hope it help!

Comment: can you please explain by example ?

Comment: <button id="add_new_option_button" data-action="add_new_row"
         title="<?= $block->escapeHtmlAttr(__('Add Option')) ?>"
          type="button" class="action- scalable add">
          <span><?= $block->escapeHtml(__('Add Option')) ?></span>
 </button>

Here as you see, i use escapeHtml for render element content, and escapeHtmlAttr for render content of element attribute (title)

Answer (score 0):

you can get detailed here official magento devdocs: **[escapeHtml & escapeHtmlAttr](https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/extension-dev-guide/xss-protection.html)**